# how to write url link in views

Tags: django

I want to write url link in views, and then return to template.

## views.py

```
for platform in platform_list:
    if (fail_case.platform==platform):
        html_front = "<a href=/home/%s/%s/%s>" % (build, run, fail_case.testResult_id)
        html_back = "</a>"
        brray.append(html_front + "X" + html_back)
    else:
        brray.append("")
```

below is the result(WIN7):

http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/6806/86730486.png

i want to let X be a link, but how can i write it in views.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise against sending HTML from views. Templates are better suited to do this.

It looks like `X` is not a "link" as your template is escaping HTML characters. Look up the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape) on how to avoid this. This documentation link shows one way to achieve this. Inside your template you can use the `autoescape` tag. Something like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ template_variable }}
{% autoescape %}
```

Comment: Wow! it works!!!thank you!!!
I don't want to write HTML in my views, but since it is impossible set variables in template, i can't deal some forloop.
Thanks you:)

Comment: Shorthand is `{{ template_variable|safe }}`